# Run Bash Script in Client from Local Server?

Tags: bash, scripts

I wrote a bash script for my use and it works. I want that script to be put in some server in my network and call that script in laptops / desktops in my network itself to execute. Any way I have made a way for that also as below.

Steps:

1. Install Apache web server in local server.
2. Put the script in web server.
3. Make the script executable `chmod a+x`.
4. Open terminal in the client machine and install the package `curl`
5. Now from the client terminal itself execute the command as:

   ```
   sudo curl -kL http://serverip/script.sh | bash
   ```

It works fine but only problem is, in my script I have used User input commands like "read variable", that doesn’t work in this scenario. So how to do that is my problem.
Is there any way for me ?

Comment: Why don't you use ssh?

Comment: yea , i already looked into it but  I dont want to disclose the user credentials to ssh to the server , so y hosted in a webserver to access all in my network. But now I am thinking of creating a demo user with no password so that any one in my network can ssh with out password and more over I will give own to that demo user only .

Comment: How can we help if you don't show the script? Is it expecting interactive input from the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
bash -c "$(curl -kL http://serverip/script.sh)"
```

This will run the script on the local machine. See also `man bash` to understand why I used `-c` option. Also double quotes are very important in this case.

Also, as @terdon said in [his comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441417/run-bash-script-in-client-from-local-server/441442#comment577269_441442), `sudo curl` is pointless. If If the script needs local `sudo` permissions, you need to use `sudo` in front of `bash` command.

Comment: Why the `sudo`? If the script needs local sudo permissions, you want `sudo bash`, running `sudo curl` is pointless.

Comment: @terdon I just used the OP's original command. I didn't think too much at this aspect. But yes, is pointless.

Comment: Yup , this is very great use for me . This is what I am looking for bash -c "$(......" great help bro.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you want is

```
wget http://server.com/scriptname.sh && bash scriptname.sh
```

That will simply download the script locally and run it.

Comment: No dude  , I dodnt want all to download my script in their local machine . I got the answer . Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in Radu's comment, why not using `ssh` to start your script from your local server?

First install `openssh-server` on your client system:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then from your local server:

```
ssh -t client_login@client_ip '/path_to_your_script/script.sh'
```

The `-t` option in the `ssh -t` command force pseudo-tty allocation.

Comment: Yup , thats a fine alternative , and I know it but my point is that , I dont want to disclose the user credentials to ssh to the server , so y hosted in a webserver to access all in my network.  But now I am thinking of creating a demo user with no password so that any one in my network can ssh with out password and more over I will give own to that demo user only . Yup